# how to fix 'create-nuxt-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: command-line-interface

a couple days before its work normaly but when i try it today
npm init nuxt-app nuxtapp in cli there's an eror saying

```
'create-nuxt-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\adity\OneDrive\Documents\LATIHAN\NUXT
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-nuxt-app nuxtapp

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-16T05_35_54_200Z- 
debug-0.log
```

and how to add nuxt in internal/external command??

Comment: Didi you try `npx create-nuxt-app nuxtapp`. this method won't need create-nuxt-app to be installed globally

Comment: i did but same error 
'PS C:\Users\adity\OneDrive\Documents\LATIHAN\NUXT\nuxt-saya> 
npx create-nuxt-app nuxtapp
'create-nuxt-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'